# Invoke Kotlin suspended function inside reactive stream

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, spring-kafka

I use Spring Boot app and Kotlin lang. I want to receive messages though the reactive Kafka consumer, and then pass these messages to the suspended Kotlin function and use coroutines there, then get the result of this suspended function and pass it to the reactive Kafka producer.

I can't just invoke a suspended function in reactive stream function, I need some kind of bridge...

I found "mono { }" function from kotlinx-coroutines-reactive and it works, but I should invoke subscribe() on this function and this is not good because calling "subscribe()" in non-blocking context is not recommended.

If an error occurs in my suspended function, the consumer crashes completely and I can't handle the errors. But I want to retry.

Any suggestions or examples how to do it correctly, with error handling?

My reactive Kafka consumer:

```
reactiveKafkaConsumer
    .receive()
    .doOnNext {
        // mono { ???

        processMessage(it.value()).also {
            sendMessage(it)
        }

        // }.subscribe() ???
    }
    .doOnError {
        kLogger.log{ "log error" }
    }
    .retryWhen(Retry.max(3).transientErrors(true))
    .onErrorResume {
        kLogger.log{ "log error" }
        Mono.empty()
    }
    .repeat()
    .subscribe()
```

My suspended Kotlin function:

```
suspended fun processMessage(msg: InputMessage): OutputMessage =
    withContext(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).coroutineContext) {
        msg.bigCollection.map {
            async {
                someOps(it)
            }
        }.awaitAll().let {
            OutputMessage(it)
        }
    }
```

My reactive Kafka producer:

```
fun sendMessage(msg: OutputMessage) =
    reactiveKafkaProducer
        .send(topicName, msg)
        .doOnSuccess {
            kLogger.log{ "Sent successfully" }
        }
        .subscribe()
```

Comment: It should work if you replace your "doOnNext" operator with something like : `flatMap { source -> mono { /* your coroutine code */ }.map {source } }`.

Comment: @amanin, thanks! That's it!

Comment: Great. Do not hesitate [to post your own answer and mark the question as solved](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). That might help other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to find a place where we can pass "mono {}" without invoking ".subscribe()" and that place is ".flapMap {}":

```
reactiveKafkaConsumer
    .receive()
    // .doOnNext { change it to flatMap
    .flatMap {
        mono {
            processMessage(it.value()).also {
                sendMessage(it)
            }
        }
    }
    .doOnError {
        kLogger.log{ "log error" }
    }
    .retryWhen(Retry.max(3).transientErrors(true))
    .onErrorResume {
        kLogger.log{ "log error" }
        Mono.empty()
    }
    .repeat()
    .subscribe()
```

Thanks to @amanin.